# Why doesn't my keymap for C-c C-c work in C++?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm new to emacs and using emacs 24 and trying to bind C-c C-c to a function to comment out a single line. I have the following in my init.el file but it doesn't seem to work in c++.

```lisp
(defun toggle-comment-on-line ()
  "comment or uncomment current line"
  (interactive)
  (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
  (next-line))

 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'toggle-comment-on-line)
```

When I'm playing around in the scratch page it works fine and when I check with `C-h k C-c C-c`it displays the right function but when I'm in  C++ the same command displays the text:

```
C-c C-c runs the command comment-region, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `newcomment.el'.

It is bound to C-c C-c, <menu-bar> <C++> <Comment Out Region>.

(comment-region BEG END &optional ARG)

Comment or uncomment each line in the region.
With just C-u prefix arg, uncomment each line in region BEG .. END.
Numeric prefix ARG means use ARG comment characters.
If ARG is negative, delete that many comment characters instead.

The strings used as comment starts are built from `comment-start'
and `comment-padding'; the strings used as comment ends are built
from `comment-end' and `comment-padding'.

By default, the `comment-start' markers are inserted at the
current indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on
each line (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the
comment and blank lines do not get comments).  This can be
changed with `comment-style'.
```

I assume something else is overriding C++ keybindings but I don't know what or how to fix it? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the built-in command `comment-dwim`, available at `M-;` in all modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, c++ mode has its own keymap, which overrides the global map. Use the following instead:

```
 (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'toggle-comment-on-line)
```

Comment: Thanks looks good. I get the error: 'Wrong type argument: keymapp, c++-mode-map' from this line though.

Comment: (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'toggle-comment-on-line)

worked for me (Losing the ' before c++...)

Comment: @aw4lly fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I've improved your code a bit, and below there's also the
code to bind the key without an error
(it happens because you're trying to define a key in
`c++-mode-map` before it was defined)

```
(defun toggle-comment-on-line ()
  "comment or uncomment current line"
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (if (region-active-p)
                (region-beginning)
              (line-beginning-position)))
        (end (if (region-active-p)
                (region-end)
              (line-end-position))))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)
    (next-line)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'moo-complete)))
```

As a side note, I *strongly* recommend against binding <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>,
as this is a very popular mode specific binding that's different in every mode,
but means generally *confirm*:

- in `org-mode` it evaluates a babel block of code
- in `message-mode` it sends the email
- in `python-mode` it sends the buffer to the process
- in `wdired` it confirms your edits to the file names

So you'll really have a headache if you bind it, unless you're
using Emacs *just* for `c++-mode`.

I've been using Emacs for 3 years now and I have `comment-dwim`
on <kbd>C-.</kbd>. I'm quite happy with it so far.

Comment: What stands against the default binding `M-;` for `comment-dwim`?

Comment: `C-.` is prime estate, `M-;` is suburbs.

Comment: Well, it's Flyspell's prime estate, for Flyspell already claims `C-.` for `flyspell-auto-correct-word`.

Comment: I care little about the settings of Flyspell or any other package, or even the bare-bone settings of emacs(do you still have `suspend-frame` on C-z?): it's my editor and I customize it as I want. And if I find later that some customization is't productive, I roll it back

Comment: Yet, you've cared enough to recommend against binding `C-c C-c`, so I expected a good reason for binding to `C-.`, too.

Comment: I'm doing a lot of programming and commenting is a *very*
important task for me. That's why it's on `C-.`.
If I were writing books and had bad grammar, maybe flyspell
would deserve a better shortcut.
One of the perks of having `comment-dwim` on Ctrl is that
I can set mark, navigate lines and comment without releasing Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a different key binding, you can use the following code:

```
;; Nothing to see here.
```

after which you can do `C-a C-SPC C-n M-;`.